# Cannot deploy MongoDB replica set on windows?

Tags: mongodb, replication

I want to deploy a mongodb replica set with 1 primary and 2 secondaries from config file as following:

the first config file for primary node

```
#primary node
#===============
dbpath = C:\data\rs0\1
directoryperdb = true
bind_ip = 192.168.2.104
port = 27017
logpath = C:\mongodb2.5.3\logs\primary.log
logappend = true
noauth = true
replSet = rs0
rest = true
```

the second config file for secondary node

```
#secondary node
#===============
dbpath = C:\data\rs0\2
directoryperdb = true
bind_ip = 192.168.2.104
port = 27018
logpath = C:\mongodb2.5.3\logs\secondary1.log
logappend = true
noauth = true
replSet = rs0
rest = true
```

And the third config file for secondary node

```
#secondary node
#===============
dbpath = C:\data\rs0\3
directoryperdb = true
bind_ip = 192.168.2.104
port = 27019
logpath = C:\mongodb2.5.3\logs\secondary2.log
logappend = true
noauth = true
replSet = rs0
rest = true
```

But i got this error

```
 ....
    2013-11-28T16:26:59.734+0700 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "192.168.2.104", config: "config\mongorep.conf", dbpath: "C:\data\rs0\1", directoryperdb: true, logappend: true, logpath: "C:\mongodb2.5.3\logs\primary.log", noauth: true, port: 27017, replSet: "rs0", rest: true }
2013-11-28T16:26:59.742+0700 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile C:\data\rs0\1\local\local.ns, filling with zeroes...
2013-11-28T16:26:59.742+0700 [FileAllocator] creating directory C:\data\rs0\1\local\_tmp
2013-11-28T16:26:59.835+0700 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile C:\data\rs0\1\local\local.ns, size: 16MB,  took 0.092 secs
2013-11-28T16:26:59.836+0700 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile C:\data\rs0\1\local\local.0, filling with zeroes...
2013-11-28T16:27:00.101+0700 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile C:\data\rs0\1\local\local.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.265 secs
2013-11-28T16:27:00.102+0700 [initandlisten] command local.$cmd command: { create: "startup_log", size: 10485760, capped: true } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:37 360ms
2013-11-28T16:27:00.102+0700 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2013-11-28T16:27:00.103+0700 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)
2013-11-28T16:27:00.103+0700 [rsStart] replSet info you may need to run replSetInitiate -- rs.initiate() in the shell -- if that is not already done
2013-11-28T16:27:00.104+0700 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
2013-11-28T16:27:01.103+0700 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)
2013-11-28T16:27:02.103+0700 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)
2013-11-28T16:27:03.103+0700 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)
2013-11-28T16:27:04.103+0700 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)
2013-11-28T16:27:05.103+0700 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)
```

And when i did exactly the same this guide 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/

I also got the same error

```
replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)
```

I dont know what esle config i need to do to solve this problem, please help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: So you did as the terminal asked and ran `rs.initiate()` and then added the members to the primarys replica set?

Comment: i run the command mongod --config configpath . and it is endless loop to print out that error, i cannot type anything.

Comment: That's the mongod console, you need to login to the mongo console and do rs.initiate()

Comment: i connect to mongo --port 27017 and type rs.initiate() but it returns error msg:"couldn't initiate :can't find self in the replset config"

Comment: ok thank you, this problem is fixed

Comment: How did you solve the problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

run `rs.initiate()` in mongo console after adding/changing the value of `replSet` in config file.

Answer (score 1):

You could write both startset and initiate in one line, it will make sure that initiate is kicked in as soon as startSet is done.

```
replicaSet.startSet();replicaSet.initiate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you on EC2 by chance? I had the same problem when I run rs.initiate() I got "couldn't initiate :can't find self in the replset config"

I read somewhere that on EC2 it always gets the localhost IP wrong, so I explicitly added the EC2 private IP in /etc/mongo.conf

e.g

bind_ip=10.1.1.12,127.0.0.1

and that fixed the problem for me. rs.initiate() now works